# Safari Youtube not centered in Fancybox

Tags: safari, youtube, fancybox, width, flexslider

trimmed down test page at www.armstrongvisuals.com/tester.php (reel link)

My fancybox2 implementation of youtube videos displays off the Fancybox center in only Safari, with a flexslider slideshow in the page.  The Fancybox overlay window is sized and positioned correctly, but the youtube content is halfway outside the fancybox overlay vertically and horizontally.  Safari seems to be relying on incorrect window width and height.  The video moves separately from the fancybox as you resize the window.  I have a Flexslider slideshow in the page and I know Flexslider has overflow issues.  Been troubleshooting on my local server. Updating the Flexslider did not solve the problem.  Right now, I'm attempting to refine the fancybox.js to rely on innerheight and innerwidth, but would love some help.  Hoping the issue sounds familiar to someone who knows Fancybox. The link tests fine in chrome,firefox,ie7,ie8,ie9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>tester</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<!--/*css reset*/-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/reset.css"/>
<!--/*fancybox*/-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.fancyboxGO.js"></script>
<!--/*stylesheets*/-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/fonts.css"/>
        <!--[if!IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/avstyle.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/flexslider.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
<!--/*javascripts*/-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/flexslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/flexsliderGO.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hider">
    <a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-necktest-Bbw.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/iHrx9wU2t-U" title="test title"></a>
    <a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-necktest-Bmix.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/aE6t1jERznw" title="test title"></a>
    <a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-broquard.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/MgQngKUuFS4" title="test title"></a>
    <a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-cleg.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/A6DyzGStzLE" title="test title"></a>
    <a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-cactoons.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/BPJBRMEnbGM" title="test title"></a>
    </div>

<a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-reel.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/oDVTf4g5cj8" title="test title">reel</a>

    <div class="hider">
    <a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-speechtest.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/5JagAzTMGL0" title="test title"></a>
    <a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-necktest.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/U-jkKFOdN_Y" title="test title"></a>
    <a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-mugger.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/cTbe0m3_ZYc" title="test title"></a>
    <a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-necktest-B.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/49ZMoplNEoM" title="test title"></a>
    <a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-necktest-Bcolor.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/mTQgA-uItHU" title="test title"></a>
    </div>
<br /><br />

<!--/*slideshow*/-->
<div id="sshow">
    <?php include('includes/slideshow.php'); ?>
</div>
<!--/*end slideshow*/-->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and where is your jQuery code?

Comment: I solved the problem. I'm a new member, so I have to wait a few hours before posting the fixed code.  I needed to switch my html to iframe embed tags and remove the media helper from my jQuery js.  I really appreciate your many answers, JFK, and fancybox is greatly improving this site.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addendum: it's clear now that I mix inline with iframes in my fancybox group, that using "fancybox-media" as the class for this instance of fancybox in my page was causing problems, breaking iframe calls in my html code. the following updated code worked with flexslider and without glitching in safari. (I'm activating a fancybox group from one link with others hidden):

```
<div class="hider">
<a class="fancybox" rel="myvidsB" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-maxscripts.jpg" href="#maxscripter"></a>
</div>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" rel="myvidsB" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-reel.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oDVTf4g5cj8?autoplay=1" title="title caption">reelB</a>
<div class="hider">
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" rel="myvidsB" data-thumbnail="images/thmb-cactoons.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/BPJBRMEnbGM?autoplay=1" title="title caption"></a>
</div>
```

with jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        nextClick   : false,
        arrows  :  true,
        margin  :  [20, 60, 20, 60],
        helpers     : {
            title : {
                type: 'inside'
            },
            thumbs : {
                width : thmbWa,
                height : thmbHa,
                        source  : function(current) {
                            return jQuery(current.element).data('thumbnail');
                        }               
            }
        }
    });
});
```

where *thmbWa* and *thmbHa* are variables designated by other code to scale my thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
First, I made certain I was using embed and iframe in the html youtube hyperlinks

```
<div class="hider">
<a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-cactoons.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/BPJBRMEnbGM?autoplay=1" title="test title"></a>
</div>

<a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-reel.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oDVTf4g5cj8?autoplay=1" title="test title">reel</a>

<div class="hider">
<a class="fancybox-media" rel="myvids" data-thumbnail="/images/thmb-necktest-Bcolor.jpg" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mTQgA-uItHU?autoplay=1" title="test title"></a>
</div
```

then added *"type":"iframe",* to my js jQuery call, and removed the media helper.  I use *jQuery* instead of *$* because I also have some mootools kwicks on the site. I also use the thumbnail helper and scale the thumbnails to fit initial window width.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        nextClick   : false,
        "type"      : "iframe",
        helpers     : {
            title : {
                type: 'inside'
            },
            thumbs : {
                width : (window.innerWidth*.09),
                height : (window.innerWidth*.050943396),
                        source  : function(current) {
                            return jQuery(current.element).data('thumbnail');
                        }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

posting it in case someone else slips into this crack.  My jQuery didn't show in my original post because I externally reference sections of my pages with links and php includes.  sorry about that. Thanks to JFK who puts alot of attention into fancybox support.